# How to use CodePro Analytix with Spring MVC project for jUnit generation?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, codepro

We are evaluating [CodePro analytix](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/analytix) to generate jUnits.  We are working on a web project in spring3.0. As of now CodePro is generating useless jUnits. It generates identical testcase. ( I have already specified spring-test.jar as the manual suggests ).

If you have used this tool for jUnit generation in Spring project, then please help. I assume we have to specify our `spring-configuration` xml somewhere or else how it will get to know about *DI*. Also, we might require to mock few of the required object, not sure though.

Answer (score 2):

Once done the codepro plugin setup, Right Click on the class or package ->select generate Junit test cases.

It will generate test class for your class. Then inside setup method you have to set the spring config XML.

**ServiceFacadeImpl.Java:**

```
public class ServiceFacadeImpl implements ServiceFacade {

        private ServiceDAO serviceDAO;

        @Override
        public ServiceVO getService(int serviceId) {
            return (ServiceVO) serviceDAO.getById(serviceId);
        }

        @Override
        public List<ServiceVO> getServices() {
            String criteria = " WHERE activeSwitch='Y' ORDER BY lastUpdatedDt DESC";
            return (List<ServiceVO>) serviceDAO.getAll(criteria);
        }
        /**
         * @return the serviceDAO
         */
        public ServiceDAO getServiceDAO() {
            return serviceDAO;
        }

        /**
         * @param serviceDAO
         *            the serviceDAO to set
         */
        public void setServiceDAO(ServiceDAO serviceDAO) {
            this.serviceDAO = serviceDAO;
        }   
    }
```

**Codepro Generated Class **

**ServiceFacadeImplTest.java:**

```
public class ServiceFacadeImplTest {
    private ServiceFacadeImpl serviceFacadeImpl;
    ServiceFacadeImpl fixture = null;
    /**
     * Run the ServiceVO getService(int) method test.
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     * 
     * @generatedBy CodePro at 7/7/13 10:34 PM
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetService_1() throws Exception {
        List<ServiceVO> result = fixture.getServices();
        int serviceId = 0;      
        ServiceVO result1 = fixture.getService(1);
        assertNotNull(result1);
    }

    /**
     * Run the List<ServiceVO> getServices() method test.
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     * 
     * @generatedBy CodePro at 7/7/13 10:34 PM
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetServices_1() throws Exception {
        List<ServiceVO> result = fixture.getServices();
        assertNotNull(result);
    }

    /**
     * Perform pre-test initialization.
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     *             if the initialization fails for some reason
     * 
     * @generatedBy CodePro at 7/7/13 10:34 PM
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        this.setServiceFacadeImpl((ServiceFacadeImpl) new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "applicationContext-facade.xml").getBean("serviceFacade"));
        fixture = this.getServiceFacadeImpl();
    }

    /**
     * Perform post-test clean-up.
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     *             if the clean-up fails for some reason
     * 
     * @generatedBy CodePro at 7/7/13 10:34 PM
     */
    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        // Add additional tear down code here
    }

    /**
     * Launch the test.
     * 
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     * 
     * @generatedBy CodePro at 7/7/13 10:34 PM
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new org.junit.runner.JUnitCore().run(ServiceFacadeImplTest.class);
    }

    /**
     * @return the serviceFacadeImpl
     */
    public ServiceFacadeImpl getServiceFacadeImpl() {
        return serviceFacadeImpl;
    }

    /**
     * @param serviceFacadeImpl
     *            the serviceFacadeImpl to set
     */
    public void setServiceFacadeImpl(ServiceFacadeImpl serviceFacadeImpl) {
        this.serviceFacadeImpl = serviceFacadeImpl;
    }
}
```

In the setup() method, we have to load the spring config xml, the above one i have loaded applicationContext-facade.xml

Comment: Does that mean, CodePro will create only dummy/skelton of testcases?

Comment: Not only Skelton, Depending upon the configuration it will generate the number of test cases for a single method. But you have to do some input alteration work. If we use CodePro just we need to give the inputs Instead of writing the entire Junit testclass.

Comment: `Depending upon the configuration it will generate the number of test cases`, are you referring `spring-configuration`? But as you said this can be given only after the junits are generated.

Comment: No, This would be configured in eclipse-code pro plugin properties.

Comment: Right now am in office, Once reach home will give you the example

Comment: Great, then join this chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42416/discussion-on-how-to-use-codepro-analytix-with-spring-mvc